# Radar Images on Google Maps API

Tags: api, google-maps, weather, weather-api

I have been struggling to find a solution for this after numerous searches.  I am looking for a web service or API or something that will allow me to fetch **smoothed** NEXRAD (Weather Radar) data for the United States and display it on a Google Map.  I have only been able to find non-commercial or pure (not smoothed) data.  The project I am working on is requiring a radar image that is comparable to what you would see through WeatherBug.

Has anyone had any experience with data like this or know any APIs that are avaliable?

I cannot even find a program that can process the raw data from the National Weather Service into smoothed radar images that I could slice up and use in a Google Maps overlay...

Comment: Can't help with a solution as I am seeking the same.  Just wanted to get you on the trail of my own research, in case either of us can make some progress.  SE question here with some code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173636/layering-radar-with-google-map-api-v3 - please update your post or answer if you've found a working solution.

Answer (score 5):

Give this a shot. It is what I am using and it works great.

Here is the link to the page where the data is coming from and they offer several other products as well.

> http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/ogc/

```
tileNEX = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
        return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime();
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity:0.50,
    name : 'NEXRAD',
    isPng: true
});
```

Comment: I've used this in the past, but the images seem to come in inconsistently some times and are not smoothed

Comment: @user1647725 If you want free that's the best you're going to be able to do. Its a lot greater quality than NWS Ridge. WeatherBug, Accuweather and other commercial sites are private feeds and they won't be sharing it. The only other option you have is to use GRLevel 3 like I have done on my site and gives you a lot more products to choose from. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxgr3radar.php

Comment: @Texan78 , I am looking out for similar thing. I know its long that this thread s not active, but I searched all over in mesonet.agron.iastate.edu but did not get wher eis this http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" link available. wanted to know where in that site they have mentioned to use this link with those parameters.Please tell me if u know

Comment: @swifty Check out the "Weather Climate Toolkit" from NOAA. There are simple batch commands it can use to convert raw radar data to geoTIF. Also, check out the "Multi radar multi sensor" data (MRMS) from the NWS. They offer free data access.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still looking... http://www.eldoradocountyweather.com/scripts/weather-scripts.php has some good stuff.

Comment: scripts for that site no longer works and he doesn't support then and is a stiff when it comes to asking for help. You're building off keeping from pulling your hair out with the option above.