# Layering radar with Google Map API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, weather

The default [weather API](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-weather) for Google Maps API v3 is nice, but I need an actual radar loop.  I found an example of layering a KML file onto an existing map:

```
    <script language=JavaScript type=text/JavaScript>

            function loadGoogleMap_FacilityPage() 
            {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.921467, -84.107919);
                var mapOptions = {
                  zoom: 8,
                  center: myLatlng,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), mapOptions);

                var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://mysite.com/southeastradar.kml');
                ctaLayer.setMap(map);
            }
    </script>
```

But the radar is not being layered.  The referenced kml file is located on valid server, and was retrieved from [National Weather Service](http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/kmzgenerator.php)

Help with getting the KmlLayer working is appreciated.

Comment: What does [ctaLayer.getStatus()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) tell you?

Comment: Nothing at all -- I cleaned up the KML file (added some line returns to make it easier to read, so I could understand it better).  After that, the KML layer started working.  

Should getStatus() show an alert box, or write to the page if there are no problems?

Comment: @geocodezip -- any suggestion on removing the two NOAA logos from the map?  Here's the map location so you can see the referenced KML.  http://georgiaoffroad.com/map.html  I tried removing the first <folder> section - no luck.

Comment: getStatus returns the status of the KmlLayer. [example of its use](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_radarKmlLayerA.html). Those logos are referenced in the KML somewhere.

Comment: Ok - got it working, but have a new problem.  Opened a new SE question for this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174552/kmllayer-causing-focus-to-change-google-map-api-v3