# Default zoom-factor of google map display on my website is not responding (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Newbee in js here ... I'm trying to display my google map more zoomed in om my website. Changing the zoom number in

```
 zoom: 15,
```

has no effect. Whats wrong here? Please help. See problem in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CoenX/z39q6vgt/).

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 zoom: 15,
 center: {lat: 52.132633, lng: 5.291266}
  });
  var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://www.tso-assistent.nl/js/TSO-ASSISTENT.kmz',
  });  
  georssLayer.setMap(map);
}
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple
// Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
// set of coordinates.
window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
    var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBqjPjdmeqpVPBJqQ2QxOvk6g8uHRTou9k&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, within your question, not a jsfiddle. [mcve] A fiddle can compliment your example but not be used in its stead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API 3 - zoom not honored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696589/google-maps-api-3-zoom-not-honored)

Answer (score 0):

Your KML layer is overriding the zoom value.

To preserve the zoom you should use `preserveViewport: true`

You should use like this

```
var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://www.tso-assistent.nl/js/TSO-ASSISTENT.kmz',
    preserveViewport: true
  });
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z39q6vgt/3/)

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 zoom: 7,
 center: {lat: 52.132633, lng: 5.291266}
  });
  var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://www.tso-assistent.nl/js/TSO-ASSISTENT.kmz',
    preserveViewport: true
  });  
  georssLayer.setMap(map);
}
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple
// Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
// set of coordinates.
window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
    var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBqjPjdmeqpVPBJqQ2QxOvk6g8uHRTou9k&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, Kiran Paul!